# How can I access the "ThenInclude() IIncludableQueryable from an Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework, I can set up a query as:

```
var query = dbContext.Organizations
                     .IncludeAll()
                     .Include(org => org.Events)
                     .ThenInclude(e => e.Signups)
```

And in this case, what is returned from `Include(org => org.Events)` is an object that can be used for another `Include()` call which is an include of the `Organizations` model. Or it can be a `ThenInclude()` which is an include of the `Events` model.

I need to include every Event property. I have a method that does this:

```
public static IQueryable<Event> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<Event> source)
{
    return source
        .Include(e => e.Description)
        .Include(e => e.Hosts)
        .Include(e => e.Instances)
        .Include(e => e.Interest)
        .Include(e => e.Owner)
        .Include(e => e.Parent)
        .Include(e => e.PatternEvent)
        .Include(e => e.Picture)
        .Include(e => e.Shifts)
        .Include(e => e.Signups)
        .Include(e => e.Tags)
        .Include(e => e.Thumbnail);
}
```

I think, there must be a way to do the following:

```
var query = dbContext.Organizations
                     .IncludeAll()
                     .Include(org => org.Events)
                     .IncludeAll()
```

And that second `IncludeAll()` is the `IQueryable<Event> IncludeAll` and not the `IQueryable<Organization> IncludeAll`. Or is there a way to define a `ThenIncludeAll()`?

```
public static IQueryable<Event> ThenIncludeAll(this IQueryable<Event> source)
{
    return source
        .Include(e => e.Description)
        .Include(e => e.Hosts)
        .Include(e => e.Instances)
        .Include(e => e.Interest)
        .Include(e => e.Owner)
        .Include(e => e.Parent)
        .Include(e => e.PatternEvent)
        .Include(e => e.Picture)
        .Include(e => e.Shifts)
        .Include(e => e.Signups)
        .Include(e => e.Tags)
        .Include(e => e.Thumbnail);
}
```

Because using a single method to include everything is better than not only having to copy/paste this code everywhere, but update all those code locations when another complex property is added.